# worker thread does not yield to the main thread

Tags: windows, multithreading, perl

I have a minimal reproducible case where a worker thread is not yielding to the main thread, or IOW, the scheduler is not triggering a context switch to the main thread, or IOOW, the task in the worker thread is blocking the main thread.

I'm on Windows 10.0.18362 and using ActiveState Perl 5.28.

foo.pl:

```perl
use strict;
use File::Basename;
use threads; 
use Data::Dumper;

# sub yield {
#    sleep(1);
# }

sub wait_for_notepad {
   my @notepads = ();
   while (!scalar(@notepads)) {
      @notepads = grep /notepad\.exe/, qx(tasklist);
      print(Dumper(\@notepads));
      # yield();
   }
}

sub main {
   my $thr = threads->create(sub {
      # yield();
      system("cmd /c \"notepad.exe\"");
   });

   my $script_dir = dirname($0);
   my $output = qx(perl $script_dir\\bar.pl);
   print("$output");

   wait_for_notepad();
   system("taskkill /im notepad.exe /f /t");

   $thr->join();
}

main();
```

bar.pl (place in the same directory as foo.pl)

```perl
use strict;

print("hello from bar.pl\n");
```

Then run with `perl path/to/foo.pl`.

The docs mention a `threads->yield()`, but it also mentions that it's a no-op on most systems, which seems to be how it's behaving for me. Another option I found was to use a `sleep()` right before the worker thread calls `system()` (the commented parts of the code). Are there any other alternatives that would help me tell the worker thread to yield to the main thread?

**Edit:**

Sorry for being unclear. The exact sequence of behavior I'm seeing from this is when the script is ran, notepad opens up. I'm expecting to see bar.pl print "hello from bar.pl" in the console concurrently, but that does not happen. The main thread sits there blocked for several seconds with nothing printed to stdout until I interactively close notepad. Is this expected behavior? Perhaps there's a better way to achieve parallel/multi processing in perl, or I'm just doing this wrong.

**Edit:**

Also, if I edit the line where I have `my $output = qx(perl $script_dir\\bar.pl);` to `system("perl $script_dir\\bar.pl")`, the problem disappears and no blocking occurs.

**Edit:**

Title may be misleading. Sorry about that. I'm bad at making titles when it's late in the day =P. By "yield", I mean some worker thread gets interrupted to give some time to the main thread. But that's weird too b.c. if each thread is running on their own core then you'd get parallel processing anyway, so "yielding" makes no sense in this context. Anyway, never mind all that; in any case, the title should've been something more like "process deadlock when using perl threads api with no synchronization primitives". That's probably more accurate here.

Comment: *"where a worker thread is not yielding to the main thread"* How do you know that? When I try this script it seems to start the worker immediately but the main thread also continues to run the `bar.pl` script.. (I am on Windows 10, perl version 5.30.1)

Comment: @HåkonHægland I amended the OP. Apologies for forgetting to mention the exact sequence of behavior I was seeing. I assumed, wrongly, that it would be easy to repro.

Comment: Can reproduce (Strawberry Perl). Looks like creating the second child process blocks. Hard to tell cause adding print statements actually causes it to start working X_X [perlbug](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlbug)

Comment: @ikegami yeah it's weird isn't it? I don't think I've ever ran into this behavior using multithreading in other languages (not to put down perl or anything). I'm about to try using some async/await library, per someone's suggestion on Reddit, b.c. from what I understand, it's more "idiomatic" to perl, but it's weird, b.c. threading isn't supposed to be anything new, so I'm just surprised. So I guess I'm going to ultimately attempt to sidestep my threading issues with some async library

Comment: Also I feel like I should reference the Reddit link here since there seems to be extended activity and information that someone may find useful: https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/nsrc77/worker_thread_not_yielding_to_main_thread/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share